# PDO: difference between two dates (php)

Tags: php, pdo

I have a table of messages. I am trying to only return rows in which the datetime_read is within the last 3 days. So only messages that have been read within the past 3 days. Here is my query as it stands:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY datetime_read DESC
            WHERE datetime_read...';
```

I am totally new to PDO and relatively new to MySQL also. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the format of `datetime_read` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    message
WHERE
    datetime_read >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
ORDER BY 
    datetime_read DESC;
```

---

**Detail information about date/time in MySQL**

- [MySQL 5.5 Manual: date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

---

**Updated**

1. Note: Removed semicolon before ORDER BY (thanks to @Sai-Raja)